# Filtering on GridBoundColumn which is not bound with DataField

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to implement filtering functionality for a GridBoundColumn. Here is how my Grid looks like

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radSelect" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ResolvedRenderMode="Classic">
        <MasterTableView AllowNaturalSort="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeInfoID,DateOfBirth" ClientDataKeyNames="EmployeeInfoID,DateOfBirth" >
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataType="System.Int16" FilterControlAltText="Filter Age column"
                    HeaderText="Age" UniqueName="Age" CurrentFilterFunction="LessThan">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                    
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

I am setting up the values in Age Column based on the DateOfBirth value received from database programmatically. I want to implement various filtering options on Age Column e.g. GreaterThan, LessThan, Between etc. Can someone please guide me on how do we impelement such option?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through some simple Javascript code and adding some components to your RadGrid.

### Javascript

---

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var column = null;
        function MenuShowing(sender, args) {
          if (column == null) return;
          var menu = sender;
          var items = menu.get_items();
          if (column.get_dataType() == "System.String") {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < items.get_count()) {
              if (!(items.getItem(i).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '',
              'NotIsEmpty': '', 'IsEmpty': '', 'NotEqualTo': '', 'EqualTo': '' })) {
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                if (item != null)
                  item.set_visible(false);
              }
              else {
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                if (item != null)
                  item.set_visible(true);
              } i++;
           }
        }

        if (column.get_dataType() == "System.Int64") {
          var j = 0;
          while (j < items.get_count()) {
            if (!(items.getItem(j).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'GreaterThan': '',
            'LessThan': '', 'NotEqualTo': '', 'EqualTo': '' })) {
              var item = items.getItem(j);
              if (item != null)
                item.set_visible(false);
            }
            else {
              var item = items.getItem(j);
              if (item != null)
                item.set_visible(true)
            } j++;
          }

          column = null;
          menu.repaint();
       }

       function filterMenuShowing(sender, eventArgs) {
         column = eventArgs.get_column();
       }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

### ASP.NET

---

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgTest" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowSorting="true">
  <ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnFilterMenuShowing="filterMenuShowing()" />
  </ClientSettings>
  <MasterTableView>
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="due_date" DataType="System.DateTime"
        FilterControlAltText="Filter Due Date Column" HeaderText="Due Date"
        AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
    </Columns>
    <FilterMenu OnClientShowing="MenuShowing()" />
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

---

I am by far no expert, but this solution works for me. You will have to tweak it to match what you are looking for. I hope this helps!

### EDIT

It appears that you do not have to use JavaScript to achieve this. RadGrid will handle the menu. Here is an updated example of the column, everything else remains the same:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="95px" DataField="ShippedDate" HeaderText="Shipped Date" PickerType="DatePicker" EnableRangeFiltering="true" />
```

Comment: Difference between my sample and yours is that you have bound the column values with DataField. Whereas in my case, i have to get the value from DataKey and bind it during ItemDataBound command

Comment: Yes, but that won't affect the filtering. The manner in which a grid is bound doesn't matter. Filtering will take place *after* the grid is bound. I've also updated my answer to where you do not have to use JavaScript.